# Compare associations between domain objects in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I am not sure if I am going about this the best way, but I will try to explain what I am trying to do.

I have the following domain classes

class User {
   static hasMany = [goals: Goal]
}

So each User has a list of Goal objects. I want to be able to take an instance of User and return 5 Users with the highest number of matching Goal objects (with the instance) in their goals list.

Can someone kindly explain how I might go about doing this?

Comment: So you want to take a user object and find *other* user objects that match based on a certain rule?

Comment: Right, by matching the Goal objects within each User's goals list.

Comment: What do you mean by "match"? I assumed it was scoring based on some criteria. Or am I thinking too hard? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most efficient way to achieve this is using plain SQL. Assuming you have these tables

```
users      [id]
goals      [id, description]
user_goals [user_id, goal_id]
```

You can have the following query to do what you need:

```
set @userId=123;
select user_id, count(*) as matched from user_goals
where user_id!=@userId
  and goal_id in (select ug.goal_id from user_goals ug where ug.user_id=@userId)
group by user_id order by matched desc limit 5;
```

This takes a user id and returns a list of other users with matching goals, sorted by the number of matches. Wrap it up in a `GoalService` and you're done!

```
class GoalService {
  def findUsersWithSimilarGoals(user) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

It may also be possible to do this with criteria or HQL, but with queries like this it's usually easier to use SQL.

Comment: Beautiful - thank you. I did change count(*) to count(distinct goal_id) so that multiple goals weren't counted

Comment: No worries. Glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple match, perhaps the easiest way would be to do a findAll for each Goal and then count the number of results that each other User appears in:

```
Map user2Count = [:]
for (goal in myUser.goals){
    for (u in User.findAllByGoal(goal)){
         def count = user2Count.containsKey(u) ? user2Count.get(u) : 0
         count++
         user2Count.put(u, count)
    }
}
// get the top 5 users
def topUsers = user2Count.entrySet().sort({ it.value }).reverse()[0..5]
```

This may be too slow, depending on your needs, but it is simple.  If many users share the same goals then you could cache the results of findAllByGoal.

Comment: Off-topic: it's exactly this kind of situation that makes me wish groovy had perl-style autovivification so we could just increment a value in a hash without bothering to check whether the key already existed.  In Perl the code in the loop would just be $user2Count{u}++.

Comment: I dunno - autovivification has bit me in the behind sometimes :) But yes, it does have its uses!

I'm wondering how hard it would be to implement in the language.

Comment: This old mailing list thread:

http://old.nabble.com/Multidimensional-maps-td19615874.html

has some interesting stuff to say about it - it looks quite straightforward to implmement.